# Title image not over entire surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to create my own beamer theme and am failing at something probably simple. Unfortunately, I can't figure it out at all and hope that someone has a solution for me.

As you can see from the topic, I would like to implement a standard image in the beamerinnertheme.sty.

So far I have managed to load a standard image. The problem is that it does not cover the entire free white space but leaves a large white bar.

Where in my code should I set it so that the image can go over the entire surface? I would also like to note the different aspectratio in this.

beamerinnertheme.sty:

```
\documentclass[%
aspectratio=169,%
]{beamer}

\usepackage {mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME}
\institute{INSTITUT}
\date{DATE}

% Content from the beamertheme.sty

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Content from the beamerinnertheme.sty

\setbeamertemplate{background}
{
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
       \fill[color=blue] (0,2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight-175);
       \fill[color=green] (0,0) rectangle(2.95,1.9);
       \fill[color=red] (3.05,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth-100,1.9);
       \node[anchor=south east, inner sep =0pt] at (\the\paperwidth-0.5cm,0.5cm) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};
       \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\empty%
           \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-16x9}};
       \fi     
       \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
           \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
       \fi     
       
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}[1][]
{       
   \vskip6cm%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,sep=8pt,#1]{title page header}
       \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \vskip0.5cm%75
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{author}
       \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor%
   \end{beamercolorbox}
   \vskip0.2cm%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{date}
       \usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate%
   \end{beamercolorbox}
   \vfill
}


\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[plain]
       \titlepage
   \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
       \blindtext
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a compilable test document, not just fragments of a theme. Please also make your code reproducible for others. Either use images we all have access to (e.g. from the `mwe` package) or provide the necessary images. Please also don't ask multiple unrelated questions in a single post. Split your problem into two posts, one on how to scale your image to fill the whole space and one about your problems with setting a default image.

Comment: Hey @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ! 
First of all, thank you very much for a quick answer. A MWE would have made more sense, I agree. I have changed my original post to a compilable test document. The reason I decided against two questions and put both questions in the one here is that I thought maybe both problems could be solved in the same code and it would be faster that way.

If something is changed in the code now to resize a default title image and I would write the same "buggy code" in a new topic that solves my other problem, that it would not then finally lead to a new problem.

Comment: If you are worried that the solution to your second question would not be applicable to the solution of the first one, you could wait with the second question until you got an answer for your first problem. The problem with multiple questions in one post is that the purpose of this site is to create a lasting repository of knowledge for future users with the same problem. If multiple topics are mixed together it is harder for future users to find the bits which concern their problem.

Comment: And also the mechanism for marking questions as duplicates of earlier one does not work well with such "mixed boxes"

Comment: If you say that both questions cannot be answered together, I have now also deleted them. I understand your arguments. I just didn't know that solving my two questions was not so trivial to do at once.

Comment: Your post still asks about two different things. Do you want to solve "The problem is that it does not cover the entire free white space but leaves a large white bar." or do you want to get an answer for "I would like to implement a standard image in the beamerinnertheme.sty, which should be displayed on the title page if I have not selected an image in the actual presentation file."

Comment: Actually, I would have asked three questions then. First of all, I would then get the problem solved that the cover picture is covered over the entire white surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {...}` you place the south edge of the image at the centre of the page. That's not where your blue bar ends. Instead you can place it above the blue bar, e.g. by using `\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0pt] at ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) {...}`

I would not recommend to specify both the height and the width of the image, this will in almost all cases result in a distorted image.

In fact, I would suggest to draw your boxes as part of title page and not use a separate background. This will make it easier to have the text vertically centred in your boxes:

```
\documentclass[%
aspectratio=169,%
]{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME}
\institute{INSTITUT}
\date{DATE}

% Content from the beamertheme.sty

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Content from the beamerinnertheme.sty

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}[1][]
{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \node[fill=blue,minimum height=1cm,text width=\paperwidth] at ([yshift=2.5cm]current page.south) {};
       \node[anchor=west] at ([yshift=2.5cm,xshift=-4.5cm]current page.south) {\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle};       
       \fill[color=green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(2.95,1.9);
       \node[fill=red,minimum height=1.9cm,text width=\paperwidth-6.5cm] at ([yshift=0.95cm]current page.south) {};
       \node[anchor=west,minimum height=1.9cm,text width=\paperwidth-6.5cm] at ([yshift=0.95cm,xshift=-4.5cm]current page.south) {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par\vskip0.1cm \usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate};
       \node[anchor=south east, inner sep =0.5cm] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};
       \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\empty%
         \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0pt] at ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-16x9}};
       \fi     
   \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[plain]
       \titlepage
   \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
       \blindtext
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Sam for solving the problem :)

Comment: @Snorlax Please see my updated answer, I think creating the boxed on the title page easier than using a background template.

Comment: I have seen it and it is clearly more sensibly designed.